# How can I modify the filename of a compiled less stylesheet in a Play application

Tags: css, scala, playframework, less

I'm writing a new `play` application (scala version) and I'm starting using `Less` compiler to manage my stylesheets.

During the build of a demo application I saw that a `main.less` file is compiled in a file called `main.css` but I would like the compiled filename to be `main.min.css`.

In short I would like to add the string `min` between the `css` filename and the relative file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable compression and the min will be added automatically to the output file.

In your build definition, you need the following:

```
LessKeys.compress in Assets := true
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but navigating in the html code in the browser I saw an error when it lunch a request for GET http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.min.css instead the main.css is present

Comment: The solution is correct. Was necessary to rebuild the project.

Comment: Hi @AndreaMeneghinello I'm happy it worked, please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.